# Spain car rental: Extra driver with recent driving license

Tags: car-rentals, spain, driving-licenses, age-limits

I want to rent a car in [Spain](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Spain#By_car). My friend who has just got a driving license (less than one year) will be aboard, and wants to drive too.

Unfortunately for us, the rental companies I have checked want a minimum of 1 year for all drivers. Example with the company called  "Enterprise":

> Todos los conductores deberán tener una licencia de conducir en vigor con al menos un año de anterioridad al inicio de la fecha de alquiler y presentarla en el mostrador al inicio del alquiler.

Short translation:

> ALL drivers must have had their driving license since at least one year.

Can I rent a car with an extra driver with less than one year of driving experience?
They must allow us to take the car at Barcelona and leave it in Madrid.

Comment: Note that the car must carry a green L-plate when your friend is driving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sixt allows to rent a car if you have a license and you're at least 18](https://www.sixt.es/servicio-de-alquiler/informacion-alquiler/):

> Disposiciones relativas a la edad
>
> Para la edad mínima y de permiso de conducción se aplican determinadas reglas, que se guían por el vehículo correspondiente y podrán incluir el proceso de reserva. Básicamente, la edad mínima para cada conductor es de 18 años (permiso de conducir a la edad mínima de 1 día). Una variación de la edad mínima es posible, dependiendo del vehículo.
>
> A los conductores menores de 23 años se les factura una tasa adicional.

They will charge you extra, not sure how much, but it can be done. Maybe not all vehicles can be rented, though. Check the details with them.

Comment: Nice! On the website, the trick is to click "Cambiar devolución" near the "Recogida" field.

Comment: @nic yep -- I didn't pay much attention to that part of the question since rental agencies usually do not care much about where you return the car, but usually do on young or learning drivers.

Comment: around 40-60 extra € each day, if they work like the mainstream companies

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can rent a car with an extra driver. Enterprise will charge you an extra fee if the driver(s) are under 25. Enterprise will allow you to drive from one location and drop off at another [Enterprise location](https://www.enterprise.com/en/car-rental/locations/spain.html). You will have to specify that in your reservation.  However, the driving age in [Spain is 18](http://www.expatica.com/es/moving-to/Exchanging-a-foreign-drivers-licence-in-Spain_107661.html). So if your friend is less than 18, he/she will not be allowed to drive.

Comment: Enterprise does not allow extra drivers with less than 1 year license. I translated the quote in the question.